# WebDriverException: /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited error when running in CircleCI container

Tags: python, selenium, safari, circleci, safaridriver

I'm using Selenium + Python 2.7 to run automated tests in CircleCI without any problem but when I try to run them using Safari browser I get following error and tests inmediately exit:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

These are the commands I'm sending to the build:

```
xcodebuild -version
pip install -U selenium
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U webium
pip install pytest==4.0.2
pip install -U pytest-allure-adaptor
pip install pytest-html
pip install pyperclip==1.5.27
pip install seleniumwrapper
pip install pycrypto
pip install requests
brew install pigz
python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"
brew install qatools/formulas/allure-commandline
sudo /usr/bin/safaridriver --enable
```

Apparently build is ok, issue is with safaridriver. I've read many similar posts here and in other forums but didn't find proper solution to this specific issue. Also safaridriver error seems pretty common for many situations that's why I'm raising my particular case with CircleCI.

Notes: I don't have a mac, circleci container runs in an actual mac with Safari installed (that's what I was told), so I can't make any manual step before launching tests.

Container build uses:
Python 2.7.15; 
Safari 12; 
Selenium 3.14

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Safari can't be triggered remotely directly with pytest command. I solved this building and executing a mac app with pytest command inside.